# ENUM constants questions

Tags: c++, enums, constants

It was posted on this site how you could generate unique enum constants by doing the following:

```
enum _EXAMPLE
{
    LEFT = 'left',
    RIGHT = 'right'
    //etc
};
```

Ignoring the issue of validity, how are the numbers generated? More specifically, what technique is used? As I wish to try to build a function that emulates it for short strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'left'` is a *multicharacter literal* (2.13.2/1 of C++03), it has type `int`.

It's implementation-defined what integer value it actually has. In particular, there's no guarantee that `'left'` and `'right'` aren't equal, so you're on to something of a loser using them in an enum.

For an example, though, GCC documents its behavior here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/cpp/Implementation_002ddefined-behavior.html#Implementation_002ddefined-behavior

`'right'` has five characters, and clearly it's not possible for every 5-character string to have a different 32 bit value.

Comment: Surely it must be consistent though? In order for the character literal to always get the correct value for the 0 - 255 range?

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent"? Each C++ implementation must define and document what value multicharacter literals have (that's what "implementation-defined" means), so `'left'` will have the same value each time you run the program. Different compilers might give different values, though. `'c'` is not a multicharacter literal, it has type `char` and is equal to the numeric value of the lowercase letter "c" in the execution character set.

Comment: Well, I was presuming that a literal single char would use the same function as a literal multi-char?

Comment: @SSight3: presume no such thing, it's not required by the standard. On a system where `char` is signed, you might well find that the value of, say, `é` is negative, whereas if you take the platform's definition of how it forms multi-character constant and apply it to the single-character string `é`, you get a positive value. They'll *probably* be equal modulo 256, that would seem sensible, but it's entirely up to the implementation.

Comment: @SSight3 Expanding on Steve's answer, it's hard to see how it could: a single character literal has type `char`, a multi-character literal has type `int`.

Comment: @Steve According to the standard, a conforming implementation is required to document its implementation defined behavior, so it shouldn't be just GCC which documents it.  (In practice, this is probably one of the most ignored requirements of the standard, and it's rare to find such documentation.)

Comment: Implementation-defined isn't the same as undefined.  There is a guarantee that 'left'!='right' on gcc at least.  The behavior is fully documented on the page you linked: "The compiler evaluates a multi-character character constant a character at a time, shifting the previous value left by the number of bits per target character, and then or-ing in the bit-pattern of the new character truncated to the width of a target character...If there are more characters in the constant than would fit in the target int the compiler issues a warning, and the excess leading characters are ignored."

Comment: @bobobobo: On gcc 4.6.1 yes, it's guaranteed by the text I linked to. On other versions of gcc, by their equivalent docs. But there's no guarantee in the standard that `'left'` and `'right'` aren't equal. If someone asks a question about C++, without specifying any implementation, then I answer from the POV of the language unless stated otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

A multi-character constant is something you'd usually want to avoid. Let's say your system is little-endian with 32-bit architecture. In that case, `'left'` translates to:

```
('l')+('e'<<8)+('f'<<16)+('t'<<24)
```

**Note** that for it to be easier to read, I omitted a cast to `int` behind each of the characters.

So the multi-character constant is actually an integer.

I once used `'BM'` to check the first two bytes of a .bmp image I read to check if the filetype is correct, but soon I decided it's not worth the extra few characters I'm saving. If you go on a big-endian system, or your `int` has a different size etc etc, you will get a problem there. Not to mention the annoying compiler warning.

If you have an `enum`, there are usually two cases:

*Case 1*, you don't care about the values of the enum. In that case, you just leave them be. The first one will become zero and the compiler fill the rest incrementally.

*Case 2*, you need those values for a clever purpose. In that case, you need to assign them one by one for you purpose. For example, if you want to `enum` your program's subsystems and you need to enable, disable them, you could have 1 variable which is the or (`|`) of `enum` values like this:

```
enum subsystem
{
    SUBSYSTEM_1 = 0x0001,
    SUBSYSTEM_2 = 0x0002,
    SUBSYSTEM_3 = 0x0004,
    SUBSYSTEM_4 = 0x0008,
    SUBSYSTEM_5 = 0x0010,
    /* etc */
};
```

(fun fact, did you know that C++ accepts the extra `,` after the last element of `enum`?)

In none of the cases you would want a strange value that corresponds to `'left'`. If you think that makes the code clear to read, you can be sure the name of the constant (`LEFT`) is certainly enough.

Comment: It's more for a clever trick behind the scenes as write-values (EG 'w+b'), so user can pass it to a File class via the assignment operator - which can pick it up as int, long etc, and treat the filename as a char array. I am trying to avoid the warnings as they look unsightly.

Comment: In which case you could define the values like the second case I said and they would pass `WRITE+BINARY` which is more readable and has the same syntax (note here that since the bits of the `enum`ed values don't overlap, `+` works like `|`