# Multi-character constant warnings

Tags: c++, c, casting, compiler-warnings, portability

Why is this a warning? I think there are many cases when is more clear to use multi-char int constants instead of "no meaning" numbers or instead of defining const variables with same value. When parsing wave/tiff/other file types is more clear to compare the read values with some 'EVAW', 'data', etc instead of their corresponding values.

Sample code:

```
int waveHeader = 'EVAW';
```

Why does this give a warning?

Comment: I am having trouble trying to understand your question. Can you make it clearer?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497192/enum-constants-questions

Comment: What seems to work and is nicely readable, but perhaps not exactly safe is to c-style-cast string literals to `int*`:  `int waveHeader = *((int*)"wave");`. — I have a more trustworthy feeling about the solution I have so far gone with: to `memcpy` the string literal into a union of int(s) and char. This introduces some overhead, but that's usually leglectable – at least if it only occurs in the file header.

Comment: On Visual Studio 2008, it doesn't seem to give a warning, and gives the same results as "int v = 'w' | 'a' << 8 | 'v' << 16 | 'e' << 24;"

Comment: Re-opened and converted this question to address C only, since that's what the posted answers are about.

Comment: @Lundin the answer by "o11c" is about C++

Comment: The dangers of using multi-character constants: https://habr.com/en/company/pvs-studio/blog/457694/

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[According to the standard](http://scarff.id.au/blog/2009/c-multi-character-character-constants/) (§6.4.4.4/10)

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one
>   character (e.g., 'ab'), [...] is implementation-defined.

```
long x = '\xde\xad\xbe\xef'; // yes, single quotes
```

This is valid ISO 9899:2011 C.  It compiles without warning under `gcc` with `-Wall`, and a “multi-character character constant” warning with `-pedantic`.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Character_constants):

> Multi-character constants (e.g. 'xy') are valid, although rarely
>   useful — they let one store several characters in an integer (e.g. 4
>   ASCII characters can fit in a 32-bit integer, 8 in a 64-bit one).
>   Since the order in which the characters are packed into one int is not
>   specified, portable use of multi-character constants is difficult.

For portability sake, don't use multi-character constants with integral types.

Comment: I'm not sure what that last phrase means; multi-character constants always have integral types (and such constants without a prefix always have type `int`).

Comment: It's basically saying that you can't portability decipher the byte-ordering of your int of packed chars as Little-Endian or Big-Endian, so for portability's sake don't use a datatype other than a char to store chars. In x86, an integer is saved in Little-Endian, a byte or an 8-bit char is saved as a single byte and technically has no byte ordering, a string of chars if we label the content as a single datatype, a string, is basically saved as a Big-Endian string. So is the multichar-char Big-Endian or Little-Endian? We'd need our int to save as Big-Endian in order to be correct.

Answer (score 26):

This warning is useful for programmers that would mistakenly write `'test'` where they should have written `"test"`.

This happen much more often than programmers that do actually want multi-char int constants.

Comment: This is a good example, but what happens when I really want to write 'test' and I have an warning. I don't let any warnings in my code...

Comment: You have to cope with the warning, or find your compiler option to disable this specific warning (that may hurt you at some other place in your code ;-) ).

Comment: Another accidental programmer error is to misremember the syntax for hex escapes and write '\0x61' when one meant '\x61'.

Comment: @Felics there isn't really a good reason to want to write `'test'` as it would make your code non-portable

Comment: There ought not be a warning for:

    (unsigned)'test'

but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 17):

If you're happy you know what you're doing and can accept the portability problems, on GCC for example you can disable the warning on the command line:

```
-Wno-multichar
```

I use this for my own apps to work with AVI and MP4 file headers for similar reasons to you.

Comment: That makes your code non-portable, especially when the endianness of the platform differs from your dev machine. It seems like a poor idea.

Comment: @Perry Congratulations! Yours is the 8th mention of portability issues on this question (including one in my answer).

Answer (score 8):

Even if you're willing to look up what behavior your implementation defines, multi-character constants will *still* vary with endianness.

Better to use a (POD) struct { char[4] };  ... and then use a UDL like "WAVE"_4cc to easily construct instances of that class

Comment: Any chance for a quick UDL _4cc implementation example?

Comment: @fuzzyTew: constexpr std::uintmax_t operator ""_cc (char const * cc, std::size_t size) {
      std::uintmax_t val = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        val <<= 8;
        val += cc[i];
      }
      return val;
    }

Answer (score 7):

Simplest C/C++ any compiler/standard compliant solution, was mentioned by @leftaroundabout in comments above:

```
int x = *(int*)"abcd";
```

Or a bit more specific:

```
int x = *(int32_t*)"abcd";
```

One more solution, also compliant with C/C++ compiler/standard since C99 (except clang++, which [has a known bug](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-bugs/2014-April/033871.html)):

```
int x = ((union {char s[5]; int number;}){"abcd"}).number;

/* just a demo check: */
printf("x=%d stored %s byte first\n", x, x==0x61626364 ? "MSB":"LSB");
```

Here anonymous union is used to give a nice symbol-name to the desired numeric result, "abcd" string is used to initialize the lvalue of [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) (C99).

Comment: The `union` technique might not be as portable as that. This discussion points at the fact that it might be undefined behaviour in C++ [Unions and type punning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning)

Comment: This is **not** standards-compliant, as it breaks strict aliasing.

Comment: This was my approach, but then clang complained about alignment issues, which brought me to this page...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable this warning it is important to know that there are two related warning parameters in GCC and Clang: [GCC Compiler options -wno-four-char-constants and -wno-multichar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47304722/4915707)