# Why are 4 characters allowed in a char variable?

Tags: c

I have the following code in my program:

```
char ch='abcd';
printf("%c",ch);
```

The output is d.

I fail to understand why is a char variable allowed to take in 4 characters in its declaration without giving a compile time error.

Note: More than 4 characters is giving an error.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755202/multi-character-constant-warnings

Comment: And [here](http://ideone.com/VHaSY0) I see that even more `char`s can be appended and always the last one is being printed.

Comment: I'm using visual studio and its allowing only 4 characters.
Anyways I did read about the acceptability of multi-char constants and I think different IDEs have their own limit...

Comment: @tristan How does this help OP? The question and answers are about `int` and "bigger" types. Are you implying that `char` gets expanded into an `int` or something? It cannot pack a multi-char into `char` type otherwise with out memory overflow. I think it's just compiler behaviour, skipping everything but the last character from the multi-char.Can you elaborate how the linked question relates to this one, besides asking about the multi-char constants?

Comment: @luk32 i thought that answer helps with the explanation of multi character constants.

Comment: @tristan Yea, I thought that it was apparent that OP knew he is using multi-char cosntant. Well I guess, it wasn't. Still I think that it is very peculiar and interesting, why is 4-char mulitbyte constant allowed to be packed into a single byte `char`. I thought that this is what the question was really about.

Answer (score 7):

`'abcd'` is called a multicharacter constant, and will has an implementation-defined value, here your compiler gives you 'd'.

If you use gcc and compile your code with `-Wmultichar` or `-Wall`, gcc will warn you about this.

Comment: Correct. A single character is normally expected for '-enclosed text. Anything beyond that (e.g., a 32 bit register/word that happens to hold 4 8-bit characters) is nonstandard and nonportable. If you _really_ want to handle 4 characters (single or multibyte) at a time, you should be using a string ("-enclosed).

Comment: @Phil Perry  `'abcd'`, as an integer character constant, _is_ standard per C11 6.4.4.4 10.  Portability problems ensue because its value is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 1):

> I fail to understand why is a char variable allowed to take in 4
>   characters in its declaration without giving a compile time error.

It's not packing 4 characters into one char. The multi-character const 'abcd' is of type int and then the compiler does constant conversion to convert it to char (which overflows in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know that you are using multi-char constant, and what it is.

I don't use VS these days, but my take on it is, that 4-char multi-char is packed into an `int`, then down-casted to a `char`. That is why it is allowed. Since the packing order of multi-char constant into an integer type is compiler-defined it can behave like you observe it.

Because multi-character constants are meant to be used to fill integer typed, you could try 8-byte long multi-char. I am not sure whether VS compiler supports it, but there is a good chance it is, because that would fit into a 64-bit `long` type.

It probably should give a warning about trying to fit a literal value too big for the type. It's kind of like `unsigned char leet = 1337;`. I am not sure, however, how does this work in VS (whether it fires a warning or an error).

Answer (score 0):

4 characters are *not* being put into a `char` variable, but into an `int` character constant which is then assigned to a `char`.

3 parts of the C standard (C11dr §6.4.4.4) may help:

1. "An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed in single-quotes, as in 'x'."
2. "An integer character constant has type `int`."
3. "The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is implementation-defined."

OP's code of `char ch='abcd';` is the the assignment of an `int` to a `char` as `'abcd'` is an `int`.  Just like `char ch='Z';`, `ch` is assigned the `int` value of `'Z'`.  In this case, there is no surprise, as the value of `'Z'` fits nicely in a `char`.  In the `'abcd'`, case, the value does not fit in a `char` and so some information is lost.  Various outcomes are possible.  Typically on one endian platform, `ch` will have a value of `'a'` and on another, the value of `'d'`.

---

The `'abcd'` is an `int` value, much like `12345` in `int x = 12345;`.

When the `size(int) == 4`, an `int` may be assigned a character constant such as `'abcd'`.

When `size(int) != 4`, the limit changes.  So with an 8-char `int`, `int x = 'abcdefgh';` is possible. etc.

Given that an `int` is only guaranteed to have a minimum range -32767 to 32767, anything beyond 2 is non-portable.

The `int` endian-ness of even `int = 'ab';` presents concerns.

---

Character constant like `'abcd'` are typically used incorrectly and thus many compilers have a warning that is good to enable to flag this uncommon C construct.