# Why will my #include file not compile?

Tags: c++

The header file will not compile into my main test program. Why would this be the case. I have looked on line but found no simple reason why this would be the case. I have tried a couple of `#ifndef`, and `#define` and am still not sure as to why the file will not include into my test program.

Below are the error message that I receive when I try and compile my test program. This has to do with the header file but I am not really sure how to fix this simple problem. Strangely i have used C++ before and did not remember having this trouble with the header file.

error:

> Error  1   error C2015: too many characters in constant    c:\users\itpr13266\desktop\c++\testproject\testproject\testproject.cpp  10  1   TestProject
>
> Error  2   error C2006: '#include' : expected a filename, found 'constant' c:\users\itpr13266\desktop\c++\testproject\testproject\testproject.cpp  10  1   TestProject
>
> Error  3   error C1083: Cannot open include file: '': No such file or directory    c:\users\itpr13266\desktop\c++\testproject\testproject\testproject.cpp  10  1   TestProject

code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef MYDATESTRUCTURES_H
#define MYDATESTRUCTURES_H
    #include'myDataStructures.h' <-- name of my include file
#endif

using namespace std;

#define MY_NAME "Alex"

void f(int);
void DoSome(int, char);

enum color  { red, green, blue };
enum color2 { r, g=5, b };

class CVector {
  public:
    int x,y;
    CVector () {}
    CVector (int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}

    void printVector()
    {
        std::cout << "X--> " << x << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Y--> " << y << std::endl;
    }
};

CVector operator+ (const CVector& lhs, const CVector& rhs) {
  CVector temp;
  temp.x = lhs.x + rhs.x;
  temp.y = lhs.y + rhs.y;
  return temp;
}

template<typename T>
void f(T s)
{
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}

template<typename P, typename N>
void DoSome(P a, N b)
{
     std::cout << "P--> " << a << '\n';
     std::cout << "N--> " << b << '\n';
}

void testMath()
{
    int result = ceil(2.3) - cos(.2) + sin(8.0) + abs(3.44);
    cos(4.1);
}

void testStorageTypes() 
{
   int a;
   register int b;
   extern int c;
   static int y;
}

color temp = blue;
color2 temp2 = r;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

code (header file)

```
#include <iostream>

int myAdd1(int, int);
int myAdd2(int, int, int, int, int);

struct myFirst1
{
}

struct myFirst2
{
}

int myAdd1(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int myAdd2(int x, int y, int z, int m, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Comment: What's up with the single quotes and the lack of a space after `#include`?

Comment: Use `#include "myDataStructures.h"` (note the quotes)

Comment: You're not using [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) correctly.

Comment: is there any reason you try to include iostream three times, using both search orders? If murphy strikes, you might get two incompatible copies included...

Comment: Oh, and if you had more translation units (source files) including that header file, you would have gotten multiple definition errors of the functions, no matter any include guards.

Comment: @Deduplicator I doubt that, seriously! Murphy or not ...

Comment: No good reason for having three of the same type includes.

Comment: @user3376708 Seriously note the other flaw about the include guards, I have pointed out in my answer, before going to ask the next question what's going wrong with your stuff!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line isn't valid:

```
#include'myDataStructures.h' <-- name of my include file
```

In C/C++, single quotes are used to quote *character literals*, not string literals. You need to use double quotes:

```
#include "myDataStructures.h"
```

The error messages are slightly less helpful than they could be because it is actually possible to have a [multi-character constant, but its value is implementation-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755202/multi-character-constant-warnings), making their use not very portable and therefore rare.

Answer (score 2):

You need either to give the file names enclosed with double quotes (`"include_filename"`), or angle brackets (`<include_filename>`) with the `#include` statement:

```
 #include "myDataStructures.h"
```

Using double quotes looks in additional directories given via the compiler's `-I` (for e.g. GCC) or equivalent option (including the issuing files directory), before falling back to angle bracket search order (that also looks up directories intrinsic for the current toolchain).

Another **IMPORTANT** point about your (fixed) sample:

```
#ifndef MYDATESTRUCTURES_H
#define MYDATESTRUCTURES_H
    #include "myDataStructures.h"
#endif
```

these preprocessor conditionals should be placed **inside** your `myDataStructures.h` file, not where you are including it:

**myDataStructures.h**

```
#ifndef MYDATESTRUCTURES_H
#define MYDATESTRUCTURES_H

#include <iostream>

int myAdd1(int, int);
int myAdd2(int, int, int, int, int);

// ...

#endif
```

These *include guards* are meant to avoid 'multiple declaration/definition' compiler errors if the `myDataStructures.h` file is included multiple times from different header files. It will prevent rendering the code again, if it was seen once by the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

Use `#include "myDataStructures.h"` instead of `#include 'myDataStructures.h'`

The latter causes your syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes `"MyIncludeFile.h"` when including files.