# C++ - to_string not working across multiple compilers (MinGW, MinGW64, TDM GCC) in Code::Blocks in Windows

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, mingw-w64, tdm-gcc

I am getting desperate.  On Windows 7 using Code::Blocks, I've installed about a half-dozen variations of MinGW / TDM-GCC, but I can't get to_string to convert my int to a string, e.g.:

```
std::cout << std::to_string(1) << ' - one' << std::endl;
```

outputs 1544173669

I've seen various bug reports about to_string not working in earlier versions of MinGW (anywhere from before v4.7 - 4.9), but I've tried the latest versions to no avail.  I've followed [these instructions](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/MinGW_installation) to install the latest TDM-GCC, changing the tool-chain and debugger settings appropriately.

All I am asking for is some kind of explanation and solution as to why this is not working.  I can provide any further information as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually printed it correctly for you, plus of cause, your Multi-character constant *(which is implementation defined)*...

```
std::cout << std::to_string(1) << ' - one' << std::endl;
```

- This portion: `std::to_string(1)` printed `1`
- And this portion: `' - one'` printed `544173669` *for you*.
- That gave you the output you got: `1544173669`.

  Your compiler is supposed (assuming `-pedantic`) to warn about the expression `' - one'`. See [Multi-character constant warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755202/multi-character-constant-warnings) and [What do single quotes do in C++ when used on multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters)

You use double quotes to represent a string, what you wanted to write perhaps is:

```
std::cout << std::to_string(1) << " - one" << std::endl;
```

Comment: There's no UB here. `' - one'` is implementation-defined and need not give a warning.

Comment: @M.M, Ouch, you are right. No UB. corrected! ... regarding the warning, Its safer for users that compilers emit a warning or permit you to explicitly suppress it. Example, like with the way they (gcc and Clang) do with expressions like `if(x = 5)`; suppressed by `if((x = 5))`. On a few occasions, I have been saved hours of debugging subtle bugs by such warnings . For Implementation-defined Behavior - If we are `pedantic` with portable C++... ...Of cause, its more of a debatable issue here, since its not a mandate....

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean " - one".

' ' are for single characters only.