# Assign multibyte ASCII literals to enum values

Tags: c++, enums, constexpr, user-defined-literals

One can assign an ASCII literal (can't call it a string) to `enum` value as following:

```
#include <iostream>
// Macro to handle BIG/LITTLE ENDIAN
// Endianness is suppoesed to handled in this macro
#define TEMP(X) X

enum t
{
    XX = 'AA', // 0x4141  or  0100 0001 0100 0001
};

int main()
{
    std::cout<<XX<<std::endl;
}
```

And compiler compiles it and generates a Hexa-decimal constant at compile time, `0x4141` in this case. It does generate a compilation warning as:

```
main.cpp:9:14: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     XX = 'AA', // 0x4141  or  0100 0001 0100 0001
```

My question here is,  can we avoid this warning?

Or can we write a more elegant code to achieve similar result, probably using templates and constexpr?

I am looking for a portable alternative, so that I can get rid of this as part of refactoring without affecting the core logic.

Comment: The "elegant" code doesn't use multibyte character constants. They are simply not portable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755202/multi-character-constant-warnings

Comment: Multi-character constant behaviour is implementation-defined. Don't use them, and your code will be more portable *and* not generate warnings. What's wrong with `0x4141`?

Comment: In gcc, this warning can be disabled with [`-Wno-multichar`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wno-multichar-608). Be aware that you're relying on implementation defined behaviour though. So, this doesn't help you, but might help other readers.

Comment: This is clearly not C. Don't spam tags.

Comment: `XX = 'AA', // 0x4141` - There is no requirement to use ASCII encoding, it can be `0x41410000` or some other combinations. This is an XY-problem. Why do you want to use character-enums in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something like this — which does not use multi-character literals BTW, rather user-defined literal called `_i64`, as defined below:

```
#include <iostream>

//implementation of user-defined literal _i64
namespace details
{
    constexpr int64_t i64(char const *s, int64_t v)
    {
        //in C++11, constexpr function body has to be one-line
        //though C++14 has relaxed this rule.
        return *s ? i64(s+1, v * 256 + *s) : v;
    }
}

constexpr int64_t operator "" _i64(char const *s, unsigned long)
{
    return details::i64(s, 0);
}

//your use-case.
enum colors
{
    red   = "AA"_i64,   //0x4141
    green = "BB"_i64,   //0x4242
    blue  = "CC"_i64    //0x4343
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::hex << red << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << green << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << blue << std::endl;
}
```

Output ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d5ed838ffbc0222)):

```
 4141
 4242
 4343
```

Comment: Note that the recursive ternary gymnastic is unnecessary in C++14.

Comment: @Quentin: Yes. C++14 has some flexibility, but my solution would work for C++11 as well.

Comment: I find this fascinating on one hand, but IMO it obfuscates the code. Better is to avoid such constructs. It is not really clear **why** OP want multi-character `enum`s. Most likely they can just be avoided.

Comment: So the suggestion here is to write twelve lines of code instead of `'AA'`?

Comment: @PeteBecker: Well, 12 lines of _portable_ code. Seems reasonable. Although as Olaf points out, you can't strictly rely on ASCII.

Comment: @MSalters - how do you know that in the intended use (which isn't described in the question) the code was not portable? Yes, all this wheel-spinning **might** be appropriate for some uses, but that doesn't mean it's automatically the right answer in every case.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I think we dont have enough information to carry out this discussion any further, do we?