# C program two dimensional array char value output for 2 character

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, type-conversion

I want to show output with a two dimensional array. I print the value of 10,11,12 but I show only one digit 0,1,2. No idea. How to output with char data type. I don't want to change the char value because I need to assign the other X and Y to number[2][1] = 'X';

My code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char number[3][4] = {
        {'1','2','3','4'},
        {'5','6','7','8'},
        {'9','10','11','12'}
    };

    printf("%c",number[2][1]);

    return 0;
}
```

So. I hope you can help me to think how to do it.
Thanks you so much!.

Comment: Did this code even compile without error?

Comment: it show 7 warning message. multi-character character constant.

Comment: Why don't you try to understand what the warnings mean?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755202/multi-character-constant-warnings.

Comment: You can't use 10, 11, or 12 as a single character simply because they are not. Each is two separate characters. You can use something like A,B, and C in their place if that works for you. I don't get that part of your question: "i need to assign the other X and Y to number[2][1] = 'X';"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing characters with strings, they are not the same. In c, the single quote is used to get the ascii value of a character, it's called a character constant.

When you have multiple characters wrapped by single quotes, it's called a multicharacter constant, and it's value is implementation defined, nevertheless it's still an integer and not a string.

If you want to have an array of strings, then it would be like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *number[3][4] = {
        {"1",  "2",  "3",  "4"},
        {"5",  "6",  "7",  "8"},
        {"9", "10", "11", "12"}
    };
    printf("%s\n", number[2][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Also notice, the `"%s"` instead of `"%c"` to print a string.

Comment: Thanks for your nice example. Any other method without pointer to print this?

Comment: @cyberoot just declare a 3D array of char then.

Comment: @cyberoot Avoiding pointers is pointless, because arrays behave like pointers in many circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the numbers into array without quotes.
`char` can hold numbers from `-128 to 127`
and also use `%d` instead of `%c`

```js
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
char number[3][4] = {
    {1,2,3,4},
    {5,6,7,8},
    {9,10,11,12}
};

printf("%d",number[2][2]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be clear, `%c` translates a `char` value into its ASCII representation and prints that. `%d` translates a `char` value (or whatever other integer primitive type) into the string representation of the numeric value. They can both be used on a `char` but have different outputs.

Comment: exactly. In the above code, if you use %c, nothing will get printed. But %d print the number.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

//if byte isnt 
defined so short

```
   byte c[3][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
```

char in this case may be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a 3D array of char:

```
char number[3][4][3];
```

Which allows `3` rows and `4` columns of strings, and each string has a max length of `3`, including the null byte `\0`.

Using something like `'11'` is invalid, as this is not a *single* character, as `char` requires. You need to make these strings, like `"11"`, or just use an `int` value `11`. If you decide to use strings, your format specifier must be `%s` instead, since you want to print out `char[]` or `char*`. `%c` is used to print out `char`.

Your program can look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 4
#define STRSIZE 3

int main(void){
    char number[ROWS][COLS][STRSIZE] = {{"1","2","3","4"},
                                        {"5","6","7","8"},
                                        {"9","10","11","12"}};

    printf("%s",number[2][1]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** Using `const char *number[ROWS][COLS]` is more flexible, as you can have any string length. You can also just declare a 2D array of integers, and you would be able to simply have `int number[ROWS][COLS] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, .......}`.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ language char data type can hold -128 to +127 range of values. That value can be stored either char c = 'A'; or char c = 65; (using single quoted character or the ASCII value of the character). So you cannot store '10' in a char variable. If you need to store the ASCII value 10 (line feed '\n'), you can use the answer of @Sagar V. If you need to store text 10 ("10" note that is not single quote), you can use the answer of @Iharob Al Asimi.

In your code what you created is a two-dimensional char array. It cannot hold text (string or char*) values. Just look at the compiler warnings. Practice the habit of writing 0 warning codes.