# GCC Compiler options -wno-four-char-constants and -wno-multichar

Tags: gcc, clang, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

Couldn't find any documentation on `-Wno-four-char-constants`, however I suspect that it is similar to `-Wno-multichar`. Am I correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're related but not the same thing.

Compiling with the `-Wall --pedantic` flags, the assignment:

```
int i = 'abc';
```

produces:

> warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

with both GCC and CLANG, while:

```
 int i = 'abcd';
```

produces:

> GCC warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
>
> CLANG warning: multi-character character constant [-Wfour-char-constants]

---

The standard (C99 standard with *corrigenda* TC1, TC2 and TC3 included, subsection 6.4.4.4 - character constants) states that:

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., `'ab'`), [...] is implementation-defined.

A multi-char always resolves to an `int` but, since the order in which the characters are packed into one `int` is not specified, portable use of multi-character constants is difficult (the exact value is *implementation-dependent*).

Also compilers differ in how they handle incomplete multi-chars (such as `'abc'`).

Some compilers pad on the left, some on the right, regardless of endian-ness (some compilers may not pad at all).

Someone who can accept the portability problems of a complete multi-char may anyway want a warning for an incomplete one (`-Wmultichar -Wno-four-char-constants`).