# removing multi-char constants in C

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, portability

Here's some code I found in a very old C library that's trying to eat whitespace from a file...

```
  while(
    (line_buf[++line_idx] != ' ')  &&
    (line_buf[  line_idx] != '  ') &&
    (line_buf[  line_idx] != ',')  &&
    (line_buf[  line_idx] != '\0') )
  {
```

[This great thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755202/multi-character-constant-warnings) explains *what* the problem is, but most of the answers are "just ignore it" or "you should never do this". What I don't see, however, is the canonical solution. Can anyone offer a way to code this test using the "proper way"?

**UPDATE:** to clarify, the question is "what is the proper way to test for the presence of a string of one or more characters at a given index in another string". Forgive me if I am using the wrong terminology.

Comment: Are you sure this "eats" whitespace?  Looks like it eats non-space.

Comment: If the code is accessing a single byte, I don't see how the second condition, which uses a multi-char literal, could ever be true. Is line_buf a pointer to char?

Comment: "Eating" _whitespace_ is more like `while (isspace(line_buf[line_idx]) line_idx++;`

Comment: The canonical solution to what?  You can *probably* just delete the second condition, since it's not clear what it was ever intended to do, and it's reasonably clear that it will never, ever fire.

Comment: Use caution when cutting out magic. That code exists because at some time in the past (and possibly in the present) that value existed in `line_buf[]`. Figure out what the original problem was and fix _that_. Don’t just remove code you think is misplaced.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: Not necessarily. The person who wrote that line of code might not have had a valid reason for it. It could have been a copy-and-paste error, for example.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: It *could* be true because the value of a multi-character constant is implementation defined. If I use tcc, the value of `' 
 '` (two spaces) is the same as the value of `' '` (one space). (Those aren't being rendered correctly in this comment, but you get the idea.)

Comment: @TianjiaoHuang: Actually, the `&&` and `||` operators are different and do enforce order. In your link look at Rules #2.

Comment: @KeithThompson It is a very dangerous philosophy to look at old code and assume that any one piece of it is a mistake.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: In this case, I disagree. If `line_buf` is an array of `char`, there is no way that comparing an element to `'  '` (2 spaces) could make sense. It's equally dangerous to assume that old code *isn't* a mistake. It could be a typo, or a copy-and-paste error, or the author might have wrongly thought that the code would check for two spaces (which it absolutely does not do).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, probably the second case is not a space, but a literal tab character, not encoded as `\t`, but as a literal tab between two quote chars.

Comment: @LuisColorado - I believe you are correct. It is two literal spaces in the code I have, but that might have been something that happened anywhere along the ling. Assuming that is the case, is replacing it with \t the "best solution"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original question**

There is no canonical or correct way. Multi-character constants have always been implementation defined. Look up the documentation for the compiler used when the code was written and figure out what was meant.

**Updated question**

You can match multiple characters using [strchr()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html).

```
while (strchr( " ,", line_buf[++line_idx] ))
{
```

Again, this does not account for that multi-char constant. You should figure out why that was there before simply removing it.

Also, strchr() does not handle Unicode. If you are dealing with a UTF-8 stream, for example, you will need a function capable of handling it.

Finally, if you are concerned about speed, *profile*. The compiler might get you better results using the three (or four) individual test expressions in the ‘while’ condition.

**In other words, the multiple tests might be the best solution!**

Beyond that, I smell some uncouth indexing: the way that `line_idx` is updated depends on the surrounding code to actuate the loop properly. Make sure that you don’t create an off-by-one error when you update stuff.

Good luck!

Comment: Speed is not an issue, the largest file I've seen, which was WAY on the long tail, was around 90k. This is pure ASCII, or at least its *supposed* to be, so strchr seems like the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

> UPDATE: to clarify, the question is "what is the proper way to test
>   for the presence of a string of one or more characters at a given
>   index in another string". Forgive me if I am using the wrong
>   terminology.

Well, there are a number of ways, but the standard way is using `strspn` which has the prototype:

```
size_t strspn(const char *s, const char *accept);
```

and it cleverly:

```
calculates the length (in bytes) of the initial segment of s 
which consists entirely of bytes in accept.
```

This allows you to test for the *"the presence of a string of one or more characters at a given index in another string"* and tells you how many of the characters from that string were sequentially matched.

For example, if you had *another string* say `char s = "somestring";` and wanted to know if it contained the letters `r, s, t`, say, in `char *accept = "rst";` beginning at the 5th character, you could test:

```
size_t n;
if ((n = strspn (&s[4], accept)) > 0)
    printf ("matched %zu chars from '%s' at beginning of '%s'\n",
           n, accept, &s[4]);
```

To compare in order, you can use `strncmp (&s[4], accept, strlen (accept));`. You can also simply use nestest loops to iterate over `s` with the characters in `accept`.

All of the ways are *"proper"*, so long as they do not invoke *Undefined Behavior* (and are reasonable efficient).

Comment: So the difference is that this will return 2 for the test "GW", whereas strchr would return (say) 11, the location where it starts. Yes, this seems like the more useful solution.

Comment: yes, because it will not skip non-matching characters -- which is why you give it the *address within* the string you wish to test.