# C language: Implicit conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from 12592 to 48

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have a char array in C

```
char value_numbers [] = {'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'};
```

but I get the following error messages in XCode

```
Implicit conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from 12592 to 48
Multi-character character constant
```

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: Well, there's no ''10" char. That's two chars. So it's going to interpret it as a "Multi-character character constant" which seems to have a value of `12592`, and that won't fit into `char`. You should post the rest of your program so we can see what you're trying to do and help you do it the right way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-character constant warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755202/multi-character-constant-warnings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12592 is 0x3130. That suggests that your C compiler represents characters with ASCII and sets the values of multiple-character character constants in a straightforward way, as if each character were a digit in a base-256 numeral.

To initialize an element of `value_numbers` with this value, the compiler must convert 12592 to a `char`. If `char` is unsigned, this is effectively done by taking just the low eight bits, which are 0x30 or 48, the code for `'0'`. (Mathematically, the remainder modulo 256 is taken.) If `char` is signed, the C standard requires the C implementation to define the result of converting the value (which may include signaling an exception instead of producing a value and continuing). Wrapping modulo 256 to a representable value is common.

Since your source code `'10'` represents the value 12592, but the compiler was forced to store a different value in the array, it warns you.

Note that the actual character encoding is implementation dependent (0 is 48 in ASCII but not in EBCDIC).

Comment: It is overly broad to say this is undefined by the standard. “Undefined” means no requirements are imposed, but the C standard does have some rules that apply. For example, the C standard requires an implementation to define the values of multiple-character character constants.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: What I meant is that the *charset* (character <-> code) is unspecified, and that the 12592 and 48 values were implementation dependant. But you are right, *undefined* in C is close to UB which is not the current use case. What should be the correct wording here? (I'm sorry, but English is not my first language and I often use one word when another one could be better)

Comment: *implementation-defined* is the right terminology in both cases (the character set, and the value of a multi-character constant)