# How to put double-digit char like '51' in a char array?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc6

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(){
char array[3][3]={{'2','1','3'},{'4','5','9'}};
array[0][0]='51';

}
```

Error warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     array[0][0]='51';
                 ^~~~
17.4.c:6:17: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]

Comment: You can't. `char` can only hold one character per definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-character constant warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755202/multi-character-constant-warnings)

Comment: Your [question should be updated](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54242552/edit) to reflect what you are/were hoping for had that assignment been sensible. I.e. What do you want the content of both rows of `array` to look like when you're done?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store two decimal digits in one char you can actually use 4 bit nibbles to store the digits

```
int two_to_one(const char *number)
{
    return *number - '0' + ((*(number + 1) - '0') << 4);
}

char *char one_to_two(int ch, char *buff)
{
    buff[1] = ch >> 4;
    buff[0] = ch & 0xf;
    buff[2] = 0;

    return buff;
}
```

Comment: `buff[1] = ch >> 4;` will store 0-7 in `buff[1]` as well as possibly 8-15 or various negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Char can only hold one symbol. '51' is two symbols. It could be three if you would write it between double brackets ("51") because C-type strings are always finished with `\0`. To hold more than one symbol you should use char pointers and double brackets or access them differently using one dimension:

```
char* array[3] = {"one", "two", "three"}; 
char string[3][7] = {"one", "two", "three"};
```

The second line tells that 3 string containing at most 7 characters (including `\0`) can be used. I've chose such a number because "three" consists of 6 symbols.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multi-character constants, you gave to store them in integral variables larger than chars. For example, this *works* - in a certain way, meaning, it stores a multi-character:

```
int x = '52';
```