# Whats the mistake in it?

Tags: c

I had to print the string but it is just showing errors ;/

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char str[] = "Harry";
    char *ptr = str;
    while(*ptr != '\0'){
        printf('%c', *ptr);
        ptr++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to print The String As Harry and its showing this:

```
Strings.c: In function 'main':
Strings.c:9:16: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
         printf('%c', *ptr);
In file included from Strings.c:1:0:
c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:454:38: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'int'
 _CRTIMP __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  int printf (const char *, ...);
                                      ^~~~~~
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Who taught you to write a `printf` statement that way?

Comment: In C, string should be wrapped by double quote `"`, not `'`.

Comment: I'm getting from this that [you don't understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755202/multi-character-constant-warnings) what the compiler is complaining about when it says `warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar] printf('%c', *ptr);`

Comment: Also note you can print a string in one go with the `"%s"` format specifier instead of one character at a time in a loop: `printf("%s\n", ptr);`. Or `printf("%s\n", str);`, there's really no need for `ptr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf()` expects a format string as in `"%c"` but you passed in an (invalid) integer constant `'%c'`.  I streamlined your code a bit too:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "Harry";
    for(char *ptr = str; *ptr; ptr++)
        printf("%c", *ptr);
}
```

You could just do `char *ptr = "Harry"` in this case, but in general it means you no longer have a pointer to the original string.